# Writing an async version of a method in a DRY fashion?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, design-patterns, stream

[The documentation of `System.IO.Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-8.0#notes-to-implementers) specifies that, when deriving from it, at most, only the `Read` method needs to be implemented.

This automatically enables the use of `ReadAsync` method in the derived type, i.e. **you get asynchronous reading for free**.

Looking at how [it is implemented](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,8c1732f39285c4cf,references), it is pretty involved. There is a custom class (`ReadWriteTask`) deriving from `Task<int>` which is responsible for the asynchronous reading.

A naive approach for one to avoid DRY could be the following:

```
public abstract class Reader
{
    public abstract int Length { get; }

    public bool TryRead(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        if (stream.Length - stream.Position < Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        stream.ReadExactly(buffer);

        // do some special, lengthy stuff

        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> TryReadAsync(Stream stream, byte[] buffer)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => TryRead(stream, buffer)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

However, after looking at their implementation, I have the feeling that the above approach may be wrong/inefficient.

Can you suggest a pattern to tackle this problem?

Comment: This article should clear things up: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/)

Comment: You want duplicate the code of TryRead inside TryReadAsync methods with calling async methods, like ReadExactlyAsync in your case. Also, it depends on requirements what methods is needed for callers: async or non-async. You can implement only one type and other one left with throw new NotImplementedException().

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes it is quite instructive.

Comment: @DenysKazakov Yes but it was more about handling 'special stuff' that I was interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This automatically enables the use of ReadAsync method in the derived type, i.e. you get asynchronous reading for free.

Not really. The asynchronous reading you get is fake-async, meaning it's just a blocking read done on a thread pool thread. So it *appears* asynchronous to the calling code, but it's just blocking a *different* thread.

Ideally, if you have a `Stream` that does real I/O, you should override `ReadAsync` and friends so that they are truly asynchronous implementations. And indeed the derived types in the framework do do this.

> Looking at how it is implemented, it is pretty involved. There is a custom class (ReadWriteTask) deriving from Task which is responsible for the asynchronous reading.

`ReadWriteTask` is more about reducing/consolidating allocations than it is "responsible for the asynchronous reading". The delegate passed to that class (which is executed on a thread pool thread) is what actually does the reading.

Side note: the modern .NET runtime code lives [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs).

> A naive approach for one to avoid DRY could be the following: [async over sync code]
>
> However, after looking at their implementation, I have the feeling that the above approach may be wrong/inefficient.

It's practically the same thing as the `Stream.ReadAsync` base implementation: toss the synchronous code on a thread pool thread. And yes, both your code and the `Stream.ReadAsync` base implementation are inefficient.

> Can you suggest a pattern to tackle this problem?

My personal preference is the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#the-flag-argument-hack); a more modern version would be to use [generic code generation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/10/modern-csharp-techniques-3-generic-code-generation.html) (as I describe on my blog).